# Android.mk error: cannot find -landroid when building GStreamer

Tags: android, macos, android-ndk, gstreamer

I am trying to integrate Gstreamer into an Android application using the Android NDK, but I am having some issues with my Android make file (Android.mk). As per the [GStreamer installation instructions](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+for+Android+development), I have attempted to include libandroid.so. Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

```
Error:error: cannot find -landroid
```

Here is my Android make file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

SYSROOT := /Users/{myusername}/android-ndk-r10/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/

LOCAL_MODULE                := video-streaming
LOCAL_SRC_FILES             := video_streaming.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES      :=gstreamer_android
LOCAL_LDLIBS                := -llog -landroid
APP_PLATFORM := android-19

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT        := $//Users/{myusername}/gstreamer-sdk-android-arm-debug-2013.6
GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH  := $(GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT)/share/gst-android/ndk-build
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS         := coreelements ogg theora vorbis ffmpegcolorspace playback eglglessink soup opensles
G_IO_MODULES              := gnutls
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_DEPS      := gstreamer-interfaces-0.10 gstreamer-video-0.10

include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/gstreamer.mk
```

If it helps, I am running OSX Mavericks and am attempting to build in Android Studio.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to a prebuilt lib file onto your existing/new NDK project, you need to do the following
1. Create a JNI folder and copy the lib file into the folder corresponding to the right architecture(x86,armeabi,mips). If you have multiple versions of the same library corresponding to each architecture, then create as many folders and add them appropriately. 
2. This is how your Manifest file should look like

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libandroid
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libandroid.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Hi G3M, thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, what I was trying to reference is the official Android C library with the name libandroid.so. I ended up changing -landroid to -l{absolute_path_to_library} under LDLIBS, and it seems to work.